# Remove dependencies in liveness and readiness probes

Tags: docker, container

I'm working on setting up Sitecore 10.1 in `Containers`. I read [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/leaseplan-sitecore-implementation-with-amazon-eks/) blog post and found following recommendation: "Configure liveness and readiness probes for your pods. Sitecore provides out-of-the-box `/healthz/live` and `/healthz/ready` endpoints. Make sure the readiness probe on your Sitecore `Content Delivery pods` does not depend on non-essential external resources (such as `Solr`). If those external services become unavailable, then your readiness endpoint would fail and `Kubernetes` will tear down/restart all the pods."

I want to follow this recommendation but could not find exactly how to do this, is this a config file update?

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore adds multiple health checks through dependency injection. In case of Solr this is done in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.DependencyInjection.ContentSearchServicesConfigurator`

This configurator is added through the Sitecore configs, so you can patch and delete it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <services>
            <configurator type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.DependencyInjection.ContentSearchServicesConfigurator, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
                <patch:delete />
            </configurator>
        </services>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

#### Update

The recommendation from the blogpost you mention is not entirely correct. If you check the Kubernetes documentation, then the Liveness probe is used to determine if the Pod is healthy. If not, it will try a restart to fix any problem.
The Readiness probe is used to determine if a Pod is ready to serve traffic. If this is unhealthy, it won't restart the Pod but only remove it from the load balancer until it is healthy again. If you are using Content Search actively, then I suggest you keep it enabled.

Comment: I've put in this patch file and verified in showconfig.aspx that it is deleted. When I stop my Solr the `/healthz/ready` still returns unhealthy. FYI This is in a clean install and `/healthz/live` returns healthy regardless if this patch file is included. Could I be missing something else here?

Comment: @Jeroen Are you running XP or XM? It can't be the Solr check anymore, but maybe one of the other checks which are then depending on Solr? Did you debug to see which HealthCheck is unhealthy?

Comment: Running XP but my code is not using Content Search. It is working now that I also removed `Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Xmgmt.XdbEnabledHealthCheckServicesConfigurator`. Basically I want to make sure my CD stays up and in load balancer for any issue with a different XP role.